# VS2019 Typescript Intellisense for custom HtmlElement in cshtml View

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core, intellisense

If I do something like this in an app.ts TypeScript:

```
interface Stuff {
    _someStuff: string;
    _someNumberStuff: number;
}

class MyElement extends HTMLElement implements Stuff {

    _someStuff: string;
    _someNumberStuff: number;    

    static get formAssociated() { return false; }
    static get observedAttributes() { return ['someStuff', 'someNumberStuff']; }

    get someStuff() {
        return this._someStuff;
    }
    set someStuff(value: string) {
        this._someStuff = value;
    }
    get someNumberStuff() {
        return this._someNumberStuff;
    }
    set someNumberStuff(value: number) {
        this._someNumberStuff = value;
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.someStuff = $(this).attr('someStuff');
        this.someNumberStuff = parseFloat($(this).attr('SomeNumberStuff')) || 0;

        this.innerHTML = 'Here is some stuff: <b>' + this.someStuff + '</b> numbers too <code>' + this.someNumberStuff + '</code> and this is your inner html <blockquote>' + this.innerHTML + '</blockquote>';
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    }

    adoptedCallback() {
    }
}

customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
```

Then the following works in Index.cshtml, but I can't get Intellisense for attributes:

```
<my-element someStuff="also stuff">This does stuff.</my-element>
```

Any way to make that happen? I tried this at the top of the cshtml just to see but it didn't work:

```
@{///<reference path="/TypeScript/app.ts"></reference>
}
@{ ///<reference path="/js/app.js"></reference>
}
@{ ///<reference path="/wwwroot/js/app.js"></reference>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HtmlTargetElement("my-element", Attributes = "someStuff, someNumberStuff")]
public class MyElementTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("someStuff")]
    public string SomeStuff { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("someNumberStuff")]
    public double SomeNumberStuff { get; set; }
}
```

Overriding the Process method isn't needed if the processing is happening in TypeScript rather than server-side.

In Index.cshtml:

```
@addTagHelper *, YourProjectAssembly
```

Rebuild and Intellisense will be available.